# Detect javascript finish to show/hide loading icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I using canvas to draw chart :

```
var lg = new html5.graph.line //(just sample)
lg.draw(itemsReDraw, colorReDraw, line, param);
```

This line take about 6s, **i want to show loading icon and when above line finish, the loading icon will hide()**.

I can not find how to detect if that line finish.

Any help or another way to do it will be appreciate.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What is this html5.graph.line object?

Comment: Put it on jsfiddle, so we can help.

Comment: html5.graph.line  is just my own .js to draw chart, what i need here is to detect if the line :
lg.draw(itemsReDraw, colorReDraw, line, param);
Finish or not.

Comment: Is it asynchronous or what? The function is finished after it returns. Put a `console.log("end")` statement below the call and you'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't the draw functions synchronous? You should be able to just call whatever you want on the line right after `draw(blah)` and it will get executed right after the draw is completed. If you want to abstract it somewhat, you can add an extra parameter in your html5.graph.line.draw function called "callback" and execute this callback right after the draw command.

```
html5.graph.line.draw = function (itemsReDrae, colorReDraw, line, param, callback) {
    //draw the line
    if (typeof (callback) == 'function') {
        callback();
    }
};
```

Then when you want to use the draw function, just include a callback.

```
//show the loading overlay
lg.draw(true, true, line, param, function () {
    //hide the loading overlay
    console.log('done!');
});
```

Comment: @Tom here is more on Callbacks. http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/